# How to check if input of all types is empty or not using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to check if input type is empty or not for all types.I am having following code.

Now the problem with jquery is that it works for text based input but when I add characters in number field then length method doesn't work as intended.

I would like to check for non-empty fields for all types of input.If user has entered anything(text or number or whatever) in the field, it should be considered as non-empty.

```js
$(".textyformcontrol").blur(function() {

  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $(this).parent('.formcontrolparent').find('.animatedlabel').addClass('filled');
  } else {
    $(this).parent('.formcontrolparent').find('.animatedlabel').removeClass('filled');

  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formcontrolparent form-group">
  <input required type="number" name="Phone no" class="form-control textyformcontrol" />
  <label class="animatedlabel">Phone no.</label>
  <img src="icons/mobile_16.png" alt="phone number" />
</div>
```

Comment: Don't go for length, just check if the value is '' or not.

Comment: If ($(this).val()) works for all inputs expect number when I add characters in number field

Comment: check this fiddle, even the length seems to give value. https://jsfiddle.net/rd6pp7ns/

Comment: Not worked for input type number when I add characters in number field

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).on("blur" ,".textyformcontrol" ,function() {

 if ($(this).val() != "") {  // Non-empty 
     // Do something 

  } else {  // empty
     // Do something
  }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input:empty").length == 0;
```

If its value is zero, means every input is having some value.